# How to stop/interrupt a boost::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I create a thread in a function,and in another function,I wanna stop this thread.
I have tried like this:

```
class Server
{
private:
     boost::thread* mPtrThread;
...

public:
     void createNewThread()
     {
        boost::thread t(...);
        mPtrThread = &t;
     }


     void stopThread()
     {
        mPtrThread->interrupt();
     }
}
```

But it's not work.How could I stop the thread?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to use interrupt() you should define [interruption points](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#interruption_points). Thread will be interrupted after calling interrupt() as soon as it reaches one of interruption points.

Answer (score 18):

First of all, in `createNewThread()` you declare a `boost::thread t` in a *local* scope and assign its pointer to the class member `mPtrThread`. After `createNewThread()` finishes, `t` is destroyed and mPtrThread would hold an illegal pointer.

I'd rather use something like `mPtrThread = new boost::thread(...)`;

You might also want to read [this article](https://www.quantnet.com/threads/c-multithreading-in-boost.10028/) to learn more about multithreading in Boost.

Comment: Really nice article,help a lot.Thank you~

Comment: You should also use a smart pointer to ensure that the boost::thread gets delete'ed.